# Shiny-Webserver Error Message curl.so

Tags: r, curl, shiny, redhat, shiny-server

I've got a Problem with my webserver which hosts a Shiny-Webapp.

I want to receive data from an API adress (coinmarketcap.com) but every time I get this Error:

***ERROR: not able to load shared object '/usr/lib64/R/library/curl/libs/curl.so':
  /usr/lib64/R/library/curl/libs/curl.so: undefined symbol: idna_to_ascii_lz***

I tried to reinstall all de libraries but it didn't work.

About the server:

```
[root@srv-lab-t-416 ~]# lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    :base-4.0-amd64:base-4.0-noarch:core-4.0-amd64:core-4.0-noarch:graphics-4.0-amd64:graphics-4.0-noarch:printing-4.0-amd64:printing-4.0-noarch
Distributor ID: CentOS
Description:    CentOS release 6.9 (Final)
Release:    6.9
Codename:   Final*
```

R-info:

```
R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30) -- "Single Candle"
Copyright (C) 2017 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (64-bit)
```

I didn't get the error I've I host the webapp from my computer (Mac with HighSierra).

Comment: Install Rstudio server onto your box too and then test it via normal R script and try to debug this way

Comment: RStudio server is installed. I get these error if I try to get the data in R from terminal:
>   Json.BTC = GET("https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/bitcoin/")
Fehler in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
  kann shared object '/usr/lib64/R/library/curl/libs/curl.so' nicht laden:
  /usr/lib64/R/library/curl/libs/curl.so: undefined symbol: idna_to_ascii_lz

Comment: Did you try this R-wrapper of the same `coinmarketcapr` https://github.com/amrrs/coinmarketcapr ?

Comment: @amrrs: Thank you. I edited a lot of the code and I'm using now coinmaretcapr. It's working.

Comment: You could post the same as your answer and close this. Hopefully could help someone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got a Problem with my webserver which hosts a Shiny-Webapp.

I want to receive data from an API adress (coinmarketcap.com) but every time I get this Error:

ERROR: not able to load shared object '/usr/lib64/R/library/curl/libs/curl.so': /usr/lib64/R/library/curl/libs/curl.so: undefined symbol: idna_to_ascii_lz

I tried to reinstall all de libraries but it didn't work.

About the server:

[root@srv-lab-t-416 ~]# lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    :base-4.0-amd64:base-4.0-noarch:core-4.0-amd64:core-4.0-noarch:graphics-4.0-amd64:graphics-4.0-noarch:printing-4.0-amd64:printing-4.0-noarch
Distributor ID: CentOS
Description:    CentOS release 6.9 (Final)
Release:    6.9
Codename:   Final*
R-info:

R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30) -- "Single Candle"
Copyright (C) 2017 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (64-bit)
I didn't get the error I've I host the webapp from my computer (Mac with HighSierra).

**EDIT:**
*After installing the package(coinmarketcapr) which was suggested by @amrrs and editing the code it's working now.*